# com.apple.named.conf.proxy missing

Tags: macos, mac, unix, bsd

I've seen a number of references to /etc/com.apple.named.conf.proxy for use with named in Internet Sharing on Mac OSX. On my Snow Leopard 10.6.6 Macbook Pro, though, no such file seems to exist. Is this handled in a different way now?

Comment: That file exists for me on 10.6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that no adapters were selected for sharing, so it was just skipping the sharing altogether.  It was pointed out that MacOS typically automatically disables the activation checkbox when no adapters are selected for sharing, but that did not occur for me (perhaps a bug)

Answer (score 0):

The file is created when Internet Sharing is activated in *System Preferences*.

Note that unix-y paths such as `/etc`, `/dev`, `/bin` don't regularly show up in Finder. Either go command-line via `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` or use *Finder » Go menu » Go to Folder...*.

Comment: `$ sudo ls /etc/com.apple*

Password:

ls: /etc/com.apple*: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @umop have you activated Internet Sharing in System Preferences? Tried toggling it?

Comment: Yes.  It was activated (checked, at least).  It turns out that the problem was that no adapters were selected for sharing, so it was just skipping the sharing altogether (I'm guessing).

Comment: @umop True. Although my machine automatically disables the activation checkbox when no adapters are selected for sharing, or sharing is running.

Comment: I remember that being the functionality as well.  Whether it's a bug or a new updated feature, it looks like that did not occur in this case.